# How can I mark a portion of R code to be bold in Latex output?

Tags: xetex, knitr, rmarkdown

Rmarkdown YAML

```
output:
  pdf_document:
      latex_engine:  xelatex
classoption: x11names
documentclass: article
header-includes:
- \PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor} 
- \usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
- \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \setmainfont{Arial}
- \renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{bx}
- \usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm,     inner=0cm]{geometry}
```

Reproducible Example:

```
first_column <- c("client")
total <- c("45673")

df <- data.frame(first_column, total)


example = paste("The fund had this much money",paste("\\$",data$total,sep=""), "because of something something")
```

using

```
\begin{textblock*}
\item[\textcolor{tasb_blue}{\textbullet}]\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont
  {\color{tasb_blue}{`r example`}}
  \end{itemize}
\end{textblock*}
```

Without inserting the text into the actual latex format, how can I put in maybe \textbf so that the currency value is bolded. I tried
`example = paste("The fund had this much money",paste("\\textbf{""\\$",data$total,"}"sep=""), "because of something something")`
But did not work.

Bellow is my desired output:

The fund had this much money **45673** because of something something

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what have to do the `textblock*` code  with the question of have the numbers in bold, but in any case:

```
`r example`
```

This is a Rmarkdown code. You can have LateX code inside a Rmarkdown code, but **not** Rmarkdown inside a LaTeX code.

On the other hand, I do not understand why not just use:

```
... money **$`r df$total`** because...
```

That will be printed correctly in any output format.  Anyway, a LaTeX-only format coded in the R side is also possible:

---

````
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=F}
first_column <- c("client")
total <- c("45673")
df <- data.frame(first_column, total)
example = paste("The fund had this much money 
\\bgroup\\bfseries\\$", df$total, " \\egroup 
because of something something",sep="")
```

`r example` 


The fund had this much  money **$`r df$total`** 
because of something something
````

---

[image: mwe]

---

But because the R code is passed to markdown first and then to LaTeX, is just easier:

```
example = paste("The fund had this much  money 
**$",df$total,"** 
because of something something",sep="")
```

Comment: I like the idea above of using Rmarkdown bold but I seem to get an error with my use case of

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.97 ...ompentation medical and income benefits**}

The reproducible example is a lot simpler.

Comment: I guess that Pandoc failed to  recognize `$`  like a single dollar sign, thinking that is a start/end of math mode, so it is unchanged (wrong) instead of be escaped to `\$` (correct). Check the latex versions to confirm if this is the case.  The solution is use `\\$` in R code or `\$` in markdown text to avoid confusions.